# when cliked listview or buttons link to defferent image in image slide activity

Tags: java, android

I want to click listener from listview to image slide activity, but when cliked listview link deferent image in the same activity full view image slide.

MainActivity.java

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.daftarisi);
    String[] menuitems = new String[]{
            "list 1",
            "list 2",
            "list 3"
    };


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, menuitems
    );

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            int position = 0;
            if(position==0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
                intent.putExtra("R.drawable.pic1", (position));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
            if(position==1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
                intent.putExtra("R.drawable.pic5", (position));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
            if(position==2){
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
                intent.putExtra("R.drawable.pic10", (position));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

I need help for my problem, I dont know how to script in click listener.

Comment: You're testing a variable you've just defined.
Try replacing if (position==0) with if (i==0)

Comment: I already your answer, but stil same. my question if click in position 1 or 2 link to activitiy image slide, active image which is per fitting in inten.putExtra

Comment: if link to defferent buttons, display defferent image slide in the same Activity.  according to the commands in the click listener

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.daftarisi);
String[] menuitems = new String[]{
        "list 1",
        "list 2",
        "list 3"
};


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        android.R.id.text1, menuitems
);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
            intent.putExtra("picture", R.drawable.pic1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        if(position==1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
             intent.putExtra("picture", R.drawable.pic5);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        if(position==2){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullView.class);
           intent.putExtra("picture", R.drawable.pic10);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

In the FullView Activity you can retrieve the drawable id for display like this.

`int picId = getIntent().getIntExtra("picture", R.drawable.pic1);`

Comment: where input that command?

I hava the FullView Activity use customswip.
the same this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nL0k2usU7I8